# Devo limitar o tamanho de colunas VARCHAR para desempenho?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Normalmente o tamanho máximo para VARCHAR é 255.

Se eu criar a coluna com um tamanho menor, digamos VARCHAR(50), terei ganho de performance ou economia de espaço em disco?

Comment: Qual backend? Access? MySQL? PostgreSQL? SQL Server? Oracle?

Comment: Na verdade eu gostaria de saber em cada um desses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O varchar é alocado dinamicamente, se eu tenho um var char de 30 posições e gravo um valor com apenas 10 ele só vai ocupar 10 posições.

Isso é válido para a grande parte dos sgbds de mercado (MSSQL, Oracle, MySql, Postgree, Firabird, MariaDb...).

O Oracle tem o também o varchar2, que suporta uma quantidade bem maior de caracteres, mas funciona da mesma forma que o varchar.

Dito isto, limitar o tamanho não vai trazer ganhos de performance mas certamente vai otimizar o espaço ocupado pela tabela.

**EDIT**

Se eu tiver dois campos varchar, um de 255 e outro de 15. Preenche-los com 15 caracteres no fim das contas terá o mesmo resultado em termos de espaço alocado, já que o sgbd vai alocar apenas 15 caracteres para cada um.

Existem alguns motivos para se limiar o tamanho do varchar, os mais importantes são:

- Evitar que o banco cresça de forma descontrolada, ex:

Não faz sentido eu ter um varchar de 255 se eu quero guardar um número de telefone. Desta forma o banco vai reclamar caso o usuário consigo incluir algum valor aleatório.

- Indicadores de crescimento mais preciso

As vezes você projeta o banco de dados e utiliza ferramentas que estimas o crescimento do banco de dados ao longo do tempo. Isso é importante para grandes empresas e órgãos públicos que dependem de licitação para aquisição do novos recursos computacionais.

Não limitar o tamanho de cada varchar pode deixar meu indicador menos preciso.

- Deixar o modelo claro para o desenvolvedor

É interessante que o desenvolvedor saiba quanto cada campo suporta para que ele também limite a quantidade de caracteres digitados em cada campo.

**Fontes**

O varchar é definido no sql ansi ([disponível aqui](http://www.sigmod.org/publications/sigmod-record/0403/E.JimAndrew-standard.pdf)), além de ser abordado na documentação oficial do seu SGBD. Então o que eu disse está lá. Não tem muito sentido eu postar aqui pois ficaria muito extenso.

**EDIT 2**

O link que postei é apenas sobre as alterações no padrão em 2003 e pode não ter exatamente o que você procura. Esses padrões muitas vezes são pagos, então não consegui localizar pra você... :(

Comment: Então VARCHAR(15) vai fazer o banco ocupar menos espaço que VARCHAR(255), mesmo que eu só armazene 15 caracteres sempre? Você tem uma fonte pra essa afirmação?

Comment: Veja se meu edit ajuda

Comment: @user26282 o varchar tem alocamento dinâmico. Só vai salvar o que precisar (óbvio,  dentro do limite). Varchar não é indicado se o campo for alterado muitas vezes pois vai ter que alocar e realocar o espaço várias vezes, para esses casos é indicado ou quando o tamanho é fixo,  é indicado o char. Lembrando que existe o nvarchar, vale a pena verificar se sua aplicação pode um dia precisar dele.

Comment: @ItaloPessoa Você pode editar a resposta com essas informações se achar interessante.

Comment: editado @edgar-muniz-berlinck :)